# Why adding randomness to a crossover operator in a GA improves it so much?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Playing with genectic algorithm I noticed that if I choosed a random crossover location instead of a fixed one for each crossover operation, the number of generations needed for me to get to a proper solution was way lower.
I didn't get the intuition behind this. What's happening? Why randomly crossovering chromosomes looks to be so more efficient?

Comment: You mention that with a random crossover location you need more generations to find a proper solution, yet you're saying that it is more efficient. These two statements are in contradiction.

Comment: Yes sorry,. What I wanted to express was the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this depends of what is the problem domain that you are trying to solve, for example in [TSP (Travelling Salesman Problem)](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/blob/master/src/GeneticSharp.Runner.GtkApp/Samples/TspSampleController.cs) I like to use these combination of operators, because they normally found I good solution in an affordable time:

- Ordered Crossover (OX1)
- Reverse Sequence Mutation (RSM)
- Elite Selection

But in other domain problems we can select different operators to achieve better results, like those one to a [Function Builder problem](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/blob/master/src/GeneticSharp.Runner.ConsoleApp/Samples/FunctionBuilderSampleController.cs):

- Three Parent Crossover
- Uniform Mutation
- Elite Selection

So, I think the more important than the randomness is the right set of operators to the target problem.